# Order the citation in winedt?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, sorting

Im usng WinEDT with BibTxtMng. My problem is in the bibliography. So, if I cited from Wikipedia as my first citation and then the second citation is the Matlab, The bibliography will not show the Wikipedia as the frst and the Matlab as the Second, but the vice versa.

And also in the paragraph, theiindex for the wikipedia will be [2] and Matlab will be [1]. I dont want it. I want the bibliography and the index is in order as I write. I want

Wikipedia[1] Matlab[2]

Not Wikipedia[2] Matlab[1]

HERE IS THE WME

```
     \ documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,makeidx]{skripsi}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \newcounter{myrow}
    \newcommand\RaiseImage[2][scale=1]{%
      \raisebox{-0.5\totalheight}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    %\usepackage{graphicx}% delete the demo option in your actual code
    %\usepackage{enumitem}
    %\usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage[bahasa]{}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    %\usepackage{textcomp}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{enumerate}
    %\usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{subfigure}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{setspace}

    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{url}
    \urlstyle{same}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{etex}
    \reserveinserts{18}
    \usepackage{morefloats}
    \usepackage{float}
    %\makeindex{subject}


    \usepackage{fancyvrb}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \onehalfspacing
    \newenvironment{CVerbatim}
     {\singlespacing\center\BVerbatim}
     {\endBVerbatim\endcenter}

    \centerchapter
    \makeatletter
    %\doublespacing
    \makeatother
    \parindent 3.0em
    %===================================================================
    \setlength{\textwidth}{15.0cm}
    \setlength{\evensidemargin}{2.5cm} % outer/right margin
    %\setlength{\topmargin}{0.3cm}      % top margin
    \setlength{\footskip}{2.5cm}         % distance between text and foot
    \setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{-\topmargin}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{-\headheight}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{-\headsep}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{-\footskip}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{-4cm}   % bottom margin
    %======================================================================
    \begin{document}

    \newpage
    \pagestyle{headings}
    \pagenumbering{arabic} % jenis huruf arabic
    \setcounter{page}{1} %mulai dari halaman 1



    THIS IS SHOULD BE FIRST CITATION \cite{ADAS} but IN THE FACT THIS ONE BECOME THE FIRST CITATION\cite{Paper8}.

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BIBLIOGRAPHY} %memasukkan daftar pustaka di daftar isi
    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtranS}
    %\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    %\bibliography{references}
    \bibliography{MainTamplateSkripsi} %file menyimpan bibtex

    % # akhir bagian referensi # ============================================

    \newpage
    \pagestyle{plain}
    %\include{appendix}
    %\printindex{subject}{INDEKS}

    \end{document}
    %% Finish----------------
```

The bibliography.bib

```
@MISC{ADAS,
        Author          = {Wikipedia},
        Note            = {"Advanced driver assistance systems"},
        URL             = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_driver_assistance_systems},
}


@INPROCEEDINGS{Paper8,
author={Emil Krsak and Stefan Toth},
booktitle={Acta Electrotechnica et Informatica},
title={Traffic Sign Recognition and Localization for Database of Traffic Signs},
year={2011},
month={January},
pages={31-35},
}
```

IM using Winedt and BibTxtMng

Comment: If you'd like to have references ordered by order of appearance, you should use `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`, but if you're writing for IEEEtranS the format is defined by them, so the choice is not up to you.

Answer (score 1):

*A priori* this has nothing to do with WinEdt  nor BibtexMng, but with the bibstyle you use. Bibtex  entries are usually sorted alphabetically according to the author's name, not according to the label.

If you consider using `biblatex`, it has a `sorting` key in its loading options. The default is `nty` (Name-Title-Year), but you can choose `sorting=anyt` (Alphabetic label-Name-Title-Year).

Comment: Hey, but Im using BibtexMng.. Any idea to order it in BibTexMng?

Comment: I'm sorry, I never used BibTexMng.

Comment: Can u guide me, what I have to do? Do I have to uninstal my BibTexMng or I can just instal the biblatex without uninstal my BibTexMng?

Comment: You don't have to unsinstall whatever. BibTeXMng is just a specialised editor that helps you writing your .bib files. Biblatex is a latex package that you load in your main document with `\usepackage[options…]{biblatex}. The syntax to obtain your bibliography is slightly different with and without loading biblatex. At the bottom of this page, you'll see some details: http://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/beginners/lesson-7/